# What is high level sitemap?

Tags: terminology, sitemap

Are sitemap and high-level sitemap the same thing?

I tried to search for it, but I can't seem to find a difference. Only a few of sites actually call it high-level sitemap.

Comment: I'd imagine a high level sitemap defines the top level site IA and does not go into specifics regarding sub nodes? I'd imagine sitemap covers the whole IA... Just a guess.

Comment: I don't think there are separate things called "sitemaps" and "high-level sitemaps." I think someone asked you to make a sitemap that is at a high level. Later on you might make a more detailed one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sitemap hierarchy can involve many levels. It won't be unimaginable to find a sitemap made of 6 levels (although not all are navigation levels).

A high-level sitemap usually involves the first level, and possibly the second one as well.

Being top level, these are somewhat the more critical levels - as it is imperative they are mapped to user needs and land themselves well to the grouping of lower levels.

The following would be considered hi-level sitemap, with lower levels collapsed (the + buttons will expand them).

[image]